# Ошибка при создании или запуске проекта unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

При запуске проекта unity выскакивает ошибка
[image: эта ошибка]

лог:

```
Unity Package Manager Diagnostics (v0.1.8)
============
Ran 7 checks
============
5 succeeded
1 returned a warning
1 did not run
============
✅ UPM registry reachable (PASS)
Make an HTTP request to the UPM package registry
>> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>> X-Powered-By: Express
>> Provider: Genesis
>> Date: Fri, 17 Sep 2021 09:39:46 GMT
>> Connection: close

✅ Ping UPM registry (PASS)
Measure the latency of the UPM package registry API
>> 5 pings made in 5.359 seconds
>> Average latency: 166.79 ms
>> Minimum latency: 166.41 ms
>> Maximum latency: 167.17 ms
>> Standard deviation: 0.30

⚠️ Ping UPM download (WARNING)
Measure the latency of the UPM package download endpoint
>> 4 pings made in 5.2 seconds
>> Average latency: 51.43 ms
>> Minimum latency: 50.60 ms
>> Maximum latency: 53.04 ms
>> Standard deviation: 1.09

✅ UPM registry download speed (PASS)
Test the Internet connection using the UPM package registry
>> Measured speed to the UPM registry: 80.38 Megabits per second

✅ Speedtest.net (PASS)
Test the Internet connection using Speedtest.net
>> Measured speed to the Speedtest.net server: 96.06 Megabits per second

✅ HTTP proxy environment variables (PASS)
Detect whether proxy-related environment variables are set (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, ALL_PROXY, NO_PROXY, UNITY_PROXYSERVER, UNITY_NOPROXY)
>> No proxy support has been configured through environment variables.

❓ UPM health check (UNKNOWN)
Start the UPM process and call its health endpoint
>> Could not find UPM executable at path 'F:\Unity\2020.3.18f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\Server\UnityPackageManager.exe'
```

2 лог:

```
[2021-09-17T09:39:45.942Z][INFO] Opened report file 

'F:\Unity\projects\test\Logs\2021_9_17_9_39_43_diagnostic_report.txt'

[2021-09-17T09:39:45.942Z][INFO] Starting diagnostics

[2021-09-17T09:39:45.942Z][INFO][UpmRegistryReachable] Sending HEAD request to https://packages.unity.com

[2021-09-17T09:39:46.708Z][INFO][PingUpmRegistry] Starting ping test on 
'http://packages.unity.com/com.unity.package-manager.metadata'

[2021-09-17T09:39:52.145Z][INFO][PingUpmDownload] Starting ping test on 'http://download.packages.unity.com/com.unity.package-manager.metadata/-/com.unity.package-manager.metadata-0.0.1.tgz'

[2021-09-17T09:39:57.346Z][INFO][UpmRegistryDownloadSpeed] Starting speed test with UPM registry

[2021-09-17T09:40:03.129Z][INFO][UpmRegistryDownloadSpeed] Download: 80.38 Megabits per second

[2021-09-17T09:40:03.131Z][INFO][Speedtest.Net] Starting speed test with Speedtest.net

[2021-09-17T09:40:14.937Z][INFO][Speedtest.Net] Download: 96.06 Megabits per second

[2021-09-17T09:40:14.937Z][INFO][Speedtest.Net] Upload: 104.13 Megabits per second

[2021-09-17T09:40:14.941Z][INFO] Finished diagnostics

[2021-09-17T09:40:14.942Z][INFO] Created report at 
'F:\Unity\projects\test\Logs\2021_9_17_9_39_43_diagnostic_report.txt'
```

Comment: Актуально, помогитеее

Comment: попробуйте юнити переустановить

Comment: @vmchar три раза делал